# Can I change the name when I download the file that I downloaded and saved in the code I wrote for the second time?

Tags: python, pytube

Today I decided to write a Youtube video downloader and I managed it without any problems. I have a question, when I download a video or sound in the code I have given below, I cannot access the first downloaded file because the name of the file that I did not download for the second time is the same. Is there any way I can solve this?

```
from pytube import YouTube

def main():
    while True:
        link = input("Please enter the Youtube link you want to view : ") 
        file_path = input("Enter the file path for your downloads:")
        yt = YouTube(link)
        continuity = True
        while continuity:
            print("To download in high quality = 1'i\t\b\bTo download in low quality = 2'yi\nTo download as an audio file = 3'ü\t\b\bIf you want to enter another link, please press = 4\n\nTo terminate the program = q")
            entry = input()
            if entry == "1":
                high = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
                high.download(file_path)
                print("Video downloads in high quality...")
            elif entry == "2":
                low = yt.streams.get_lowest_resolution()
                low.download(file_path)
                print("Video downloads in low quality...")
            elif entry == "3":
                audio = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
                audio.download(file_path)
                print("Downloading audio file...")
            elif entry == "4":
                print("Please wait...")
                continuity = False
            elif entry.lower() == "q":
                print("Thank you for using our application. \nhttps://github.com/Batuhanaydn")
                exit()
            else:
                print("You entered an unknown login")
                break

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the file name you are downloading

`stream.download(filename='something')`

when writing filename, you don't need to include the suffix, eg: .mp4 .mp3